# Python Matplotlib: Clear figure when figure window is not open

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm working with matplotlib plotting and use `ioff()` to switch interactive mode off to suppress the automatic opening of the plotting window on figrue creation. I want to have full control over the figure and only see it when explicitely using the `show()` command.

Now apparently the built-in commands to clear figures and axes do not work properly anymore.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpp

class PlotTest:

    def __init__(self,nx=1,ny=1):
        # Switch off interactive mode:
        mpp.ioff()

        # Create Figure and Axes:
        self.createFigure(nx, ny)

    def createFigure(self,nx=1,ny=1):
        self.fig, self.axes = mpp.subplots(nx,ny)
        if nx*ny == 1:
            self.axes = np.array([self.axes])

    def linePlot(self):
        X = np.linspace(0,20,21)
        Y = np.random.rand(21)     
        self.axes[0].plot(X,Y)

P = PlotTest()
P.linePlot()
P.fig.show()
```

Now I was thinking I could use `P.fig.clear()` any time to simply clear `P.fig`, but apparently that's not the case.

Writing `P.fig.clear()` directly into the script and execute it together it works and all I see is an empty figure. However that's rather pointless as I never get to see the actual plot like that.

Doing `P.fig.clear()` manually in the console does not do anything, regardless if the plot window is open or not, all other possible commands fail as well:

```
P.fig.clf()
P.axes[0].clear()
P.axes[0].cla()
mpp.clf()
mpp.cla()
mpp.close(P.fig)
```

Wrapping the command into a class method doesn't work either:

```
def clearFig(self):
    self.fig.clear()
```

EDIT ================

After a `clear()` `fig.axes` is empty, yet `show()` still shows the old plot with the axes still being plotted.

/EDIT ================

Is it because I switched off interactive mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a call to `plt.draw()` after `P.fig.clear()` it clears the figure. From the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.draw),

> This is used in interactive mode to update a figure that has been altered, but not automatically re-drawn. This should be only rarely needed, but there may be ways to modify the state of a figure with out marking it as stale. Please report these cases as bugs.

I guess this is not a bug as you have switched off interactive mode so it is now your responsibility to explicitly redraw when you want to.

You can also use `P.fig.canvas.draw_idle()` which could be wrapper in the class as `clearFigure` method.

Comment: Thanks, `P.fig.canvas.draw_idle()` seems to work in my example, will try and see if it really does the trick.